# Pixel widths and heights of buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my Tkinter program, I have experimented a way to expand the size of a button in Python. When I tried these "width" and "height" stuff, all I got is something that looks really messy, possibly referring to just the widths and heights in terms of size of the font. And when I tried to add "px" to the ends of each number, I just get an error. How do I adjust the size of a button in pixels?

Here is my current code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

button_qwer = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", width="10", height="10")
button_asdf = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", width="20", height="20")
button_zxcv = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", width="30", height="30")

button_qwer.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_asdf.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_zxcv.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the button has an image, the width and height are in pixels. If it doesn't have an image, the width and height are in the number of characters based on the size of the character "0" (zero) of the font that the button is using. If it has both an image and text, the values are in pixels.

### Using an invisible image

One solution is to give it an invisible image so that the attributes are treated as pixels. The buttons still won't be that exact size because of the extra decorations such as the border and highlight ring. If you want a precise size, you'll need to set those options to zero as well, or adjust the width to account for the border widths.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

null_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=0, height=0)

button_qwer = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", width="10", height="10",
                     image=null_image, compound="center", borderwidth=0,
                     highlightthickness=0, padx=0, pady=0)
button_asdf = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", width="20", height="20",
                     image=null_image, compound="center", borderwidth=0,
                     highlightthickness=0, padx=0, pady=0)
button_zxcv = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", width="30", height="30",
                     image=null_image, compound="center", borderwidth=0,
                     highlightthickness=0, padx=0, pady=0)

button_qwer.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_asdf.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_zxcv.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

### Using a frame

Another solution would be to create a frame with a specific size, and then use `place` to put the button in the frame such that it fills the frame.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=10, height=10)
f2 = tk.Frame(root, width=20, height=20)
f3 = tk.Frame(root, width=30, height=30)

f1.grid(row=0, column=0)
f2.grid(row=0, column=1)
f3.grid(row=0, column=2)

button_qwer = Button(f1, text="asdfasdf")
button_asdf = Button(f2, text="asdfasdf")
button_zxcv = Button(f3, text="asdfasdf")

button_qwer.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
button_asdf.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
button_zxcv.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are there any specific advantages or disadvantages to each method?

Comment: @RonZhang: not really, other than the use of frames means you have more widgets. I don't see that as a big deal.

Comment: Some potential disadvantages/advantages may arise when certain pieces of additional code cannot be written in certain occasions. At the moment, I assume that all of the pieces of code are pretty much the same besides having more widgets, but I am not quite sure if it really has purely no problematic difference besides number of widgets. Would you like to verify to me whether you have identified any potential issues with addition of certain pieces of other code between using an invisible image and a frame?

Comment: One potential disadvantage I have potentially identified for the invisible image example could be that I might not be able to put both invisible images and non-invisible images at the same button, isn't it? I haven't tested it, but nevertheless I'd be truly interested to know the advantages/disadvantages of each method.

Comment: @RonZhang: if you need a non-invisible image, you don't need an invisible image. You just need an image.

Comment: @RonZhang _"I am not quite sure if it really has purely no problematic difference besides number of widgets"_ - there really are no big problematic differences.